# Convert dataframe values into str where is not null (None)

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I need to ingest data into a SQL Server database using Python, so in order to do that I'm casting all my dataframe into str before:

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

But if my dataframe has null values as `None`, the `None` word is also casting as string and ingested as string into my database as well as example below.

| Row | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | None |
| 2 | projects |
| 3 | projects |
| 4 | projects |
| 5 | None |

I couldn't find a way to apply a cast using `astype(str)` in my dataframe where the values is not null.

The output I need:

| Row | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | projects |
| 3 | projects |
| 4 | projects |
| 5 |  |

What is the best way to do that?

[EDIT]

I'm already using for the whole dataframe because I've got a lot of columns: `df = df.str.replace('None', '')`, but I'm afraid any "None" word can appear somewhere and be replaced wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.replace`:

```
# After df = df.astype(str)
df['Type'] = df['Type'].str.replace('None', '')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Row       Type
0     1
1     2  projects
2     3  projects
3     4  projects
4     5
```

[EDIT]

According to your comment, the method below replace cells that contain only None over your whole dataframe.

```
df = df.replace(r'^None$', '', regex=True)
```

Note: `^` matches the start of line and `$` matches the end of line.

Comment: I'm already using for the whole dataframe because I've got a lot of columns: `df = df.str.replace('None', '')`, but I'm afraid any "None" word can appear somewhere and be replaced wrong. Is there anyway how to that by using `apply` filtering the dataframe?

Comment: It's a simple solution and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe/ Example:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[None,None,None], 'col2': ['Nonevent',None,'Nonsuch'], 'col3': [None, 'Nonequivalence', None]})

df = df.astype(str)

print(df, '\n')

# currently looks like..
# 
#    col1      col2            col3
# 0  None  Nonevent            None
# 1  None      None  Nonequivalence
# 2  None   Nonsuch            None

# create a list of the current columns/remove any that should not be touched
cols = df.columns.to_list()
cols.remove('col3')

# from the filtered columns find the rows with 'None'
filter = df.loc[:,cols] == 'None'

# apply the filter and remove the 'None' values only from the columns required
df[filter] = ''

print(df)

# in this case only col1 and col2 are affected
#     col1      col2            col3
# 0         Nonevent            None
# 1                   Nonequivalence
# 2          Nonsuch            None
```

**Output (before and after):**

```
   col1      col2            col3
0  None  Nonevent            None
1  None      None  Nonequivalence
2  None   Nonsuch            None 



  col1       col2            col3
0        Nonevent            None
1                  Nonequivalence
2         Nonsuch            None
```